# Getting the list of staged files of type `.js`

Tags: git

I can get the list of staged files using the command `git diff --name-only --cached` . But I need the list of staged files of type `.js`. Is there any way I could get it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+pattern

Answer (score 2):

Try this option, which uses the glob pattern `*.js` to target only JavaScript files:

```
git diff --name-only --cached -- '*.js'
```

Comment: @Santosh Can you _accept_ this answer if it resolved your problem?